# Recursive Proof relating to Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble with this problem:

If $a_n$ is the number of ordered trees with $n+1$ vertices, recursively prove that $a_n$ is the $n$th Catalan number.

I am not sure what it means to 'recursively prove' as this sounds like induction to me but it is apparent that the problem is not asking for induction.  I am having trouble getting a start on this so I am hoping someone is familiar with this type of problem.

Comment: Yes, recursive proof = proof by induction (or strong induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a standard recursion for the Catalan numbers, namely
$$C_{n+1} = C_0 C_n + C_1 C_{n-1} + \cdots + C_n C_0,$$
which, along with the initial value $C_0 = 1$, determines the sequence of Catalan numbers.

If you show that $a_n$ satisfies the same recurrence and the same initial condition, then you have a proof that $a_n = C_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am now looking into how to categorize each term in the recurrence (i.e . $a_n = a_0a_{n-1} + ... + a_{n-1}a_0$.  It seems to me that there should be a categorization based on how many nodes are connected to the root but nothing clear yet.  Do you happen to have a suggestion for this?